# Enable PHP for Apache on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, macos

I tried to enable Apache and PHP for Apache on MAC OS X Yosemite. I succeeded with enabling Apache but wasn't able to enable PHP for Apache.

I was following this tutorial to enable PHP - http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/

According to the above tutorial, when I'm trying to find httpd.conf file under DocumentRoot (/Library/WebServer/Documents), I'm getting the below error as http.conf isn't available there at all.

[image]
.

Comment: What about `grep php httpd.conf | grep so httpd.conf`? Does that show any lines? You might have to enable the `modphp` extension for Apache, which is usually on a line like `LoadModule php5_module path/to/apache/modules/libphp5.so` (replace `php5` with `php7` if you are using `php7`).

Comment: I've enabled LoadModule php5_module path/to/apache/modules/libphp5.so by uncommenting it as suggested in above tutorial and restarted apache, but always gets stuck with above error. Sorry I'm not much php guy, so if there is missing something let me know

Comment: No worries. What error are you getting? I don't see any error in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: It says access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot, is this the error or some message? As later on I've created a php file echo '<?php phpinfo();' > /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php command and tried to access http://localhost/phpinfo.php but it shows NOT FOUND

Comment: That is not an error message. It's a comment in the configuration file.

Comment: Okay. But I created a php file and it shows NOT FOUND in localhost/phpinfo.php - can you help me how to solve it

Comment: What do you see on `http://localhost` in your web browser?

Comment: It Works! in http://localhost

Comment: What do you mean, it works? Does PHP work as expected?

Comment: in http://localhost - it shows 
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102241/discussion-between-conradk-and-kiran-jasvanee).

Comment: http://localhost is working fine. the file I created named phpinfo.php seems to not being found